# sh executable if else statement

Tags: if-statement, sh, counter, executable

How do I test with a sh script if an executable outputs a certain string? I run the executable with `./program` and it prints to the console either `hello` or `goodbye`. I want to run it 1000 times and count how many times each output appears.

```
#!/bin/sh
count=0
secs=60                        # Set interval (duration) in seconds.
endTime=$(( $(date +%s) + secs )) # Calculate end time.

while [ $(date +%s) -lt $endTime ]; do  # Loop until interval has elapsed.
    if [[ ./program = *hello* ]]; then
        count++
    fi
done
```

edit (partially fixed a according to answer given):

```
#!/bin/sh


winCount=0
totalCount=0
secs=60                        # Set interval (duration) in seconds.
endTime=$(( $(date +%s) + secs )) # Calculate end time.

while [ $(date +%s) -lt $endTime ]; do  # Loop until interval has elapsed.
        totalCount++
        case $(./program) in
                *\[1\]\ \[1\]\ \[1\]* )((winCount++)) ;;
        esac
done
echo "wins=$winCount"
echo "total=$totalCount"
```

Comment: at least edit your Q to show how you propose to run your program 1000 times. Good luck.

Comment: Really I need to run it for one minute, I was just trying to simplify the question. I'll edit with code.

Comment: `((totalCnt++))` OK? ;-) Good luck

Comment: What is the significance of the `edit:` section in your question? If that is in response to @shelter please add a remark to explain why it is there (or simply remove the first copy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit**

Try

```
#!/bin/bash
runCount=0
secs=60                        # Set interval (duration) in seconds.
endTime=$(( $(date +%s) + secs )) # Calculate end time.

while [ $(date +%s) -lt $endTime ]; do  # Loop until interval has elapsed.
  # bash/ksh only ((runCount++))
  runCount=$(expr $runCount + 1 )
  case $(./program) in
      *\[1\]\ \[1\] ) ((matchCnt++)) ;;
  esac
done
echo "avg=$(( runCount / matchCnt ))"
```

**orig**

You're very close. Why not use the unappreciated `case` statement, ie.

```
#!/bin/sh
count=0
secs=60                        # Set interval (duration) in seconds.
endTime=$(( $(date +%s) + secs )) # Calculate end time.

while [ $(date +%s) -lt $endTime ]; do  # Loop until interval has elapsed.
  case $(./program) in
      *hello* )((helloCnt++)) ;;
      *goodbye* ) ((goodbyeCnt++)) ;;
  esac
done
echo "hellos=$helloCnt    goodByes=$goodbyCnt"
```

I can't think of an easy substitute for `./program`, so I can't test this.

If you get error msgs, let me know.

Also, if your goal is to run this as fast as possible, using a counter for the loop would eliminate the relatively expensive call to `$(date +%s)` to drive your loop. i.e.

```
 for (i=0;i<1000;i++) ; do
     case $(./program) in
         ...
     esac
 done
```

IHTH

Comment: Thanks. I'm still having two problems. First, the actual string I want to check for is "[1] [1] [1]" and since the brackets are special characters this isn't working and I can't seem to escape them properly. The second problem is that for some reason even though at the top I set count=0, when I run the program it says "count++: not found"

Comment: My end goal is really trying to figure out the percentage occurrence of the output "[1] [1] [1]" over a one-minute run of the program. I'm trying to count the number of total runs and the number of runs that produce this output in order to figure this out.

Comment: Ah, still learning to write a useable specification. OK ;-) .. Let me do some testing. I'm pretty sure we can escape `[1]`s.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like I can do `*\[1\]*`, but when I try to do `*\[1\] \[1\]*` it errors.

Comment: esace the space char as well, i.e. `\[1\]\ \[1\]`.

Comment: great that worked ;) now the only problem is for some reason iterating the counters isn't working. I'll update my post with the current code I'm using.

Comment: var++ needs to be either inside `$(( var++))` or if `var` is just being used by shell calcs, leave in `(( var++ ))`. See my *edit* above. Good luck.

Comment: can you switch to `#!/bin/bash` (or `#!/bin/ksh`)?

Comment: hmm I tried that and it still says `runCount++: not found`. Is it possible that iterating with ++ can't be used in sh?

Comment: That worked, I should have thought of that ^^ thanks again.

Comment: I've edited in the `++` syntax that works with `#!/bin/sh`. do `runCount=$(expr $runCount + 1)`. Tnx. Glad that helped. Good luck

Comment: `runCount=$(( runCount+1 ))` or `: $((runCount+=1))` should work fine with any POSIX shell.

Comment: @chepner, yep, I'm sure you're right I still think of #!/bin/sh in terms of Sun3, etc, which didn't have nicietes of `$(( math expr))` (as I'm sure you know). Thanks for the reminder on newer syntax. Good luck to all.